# When can I omit "how" from "how to"?

Tags: word-usage

What's the difference between:

> 1 Teach your son how to be accountable?

> 2 Teach your son to be accountable?

If I can use the second one when can I omit "how"?

Comment: 1 concerns the manner of achieving the goal. 2 simply concerns the goal itself. The choice depends on your intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two sentences have significantly different meanings.

> 1 Teach your son how to be accountable?

> 2 Teach your son to be accountable?

1 says to teach your son the **method** of being accountable. The techniques that support accountability.

2 says to teach your son the **value** of being accountable. That is, that he **ought to be** accountable. Quite different

Comment: twp, hav, toi, beoing? Started celebrating early?

Comment: @old, no, poor typist, now having some vision issues which makes me worse.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. If I notice any errors I'll just quietly correct them.